# Gradle Android-Studio: deploy / run on multiple devices parallel

Tags: deployment, parallel-processing, gradle, android-studio, device

I came from Intellij (and ANT) and there I can run an apk if more than one devices are connected. Then I get a chooser dialog with all connected devices(offline and online).
Now I work with Android-Studio and gradle and if I deploy with run or whatever (installDebug, clean etc.), it deploys automatically on the device (and AFTER deploying on device i get the chooser dialog). If I connected more than one device, than he faild the build with the message "more than one device".

Its possible with configuration in Android-studio, compile or gradle task or in build.gradle to get again the chooser dialog with all connected devices again? I loved the intellij Feature for deploying one apk on multiple devices parallel.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my deploy prozess i used the gradle statements gradle run, install or clean. This are Tasks, there deploy automatically. i use now assemble gradle task and now it works, sorry for confusing

Answer (score 10):

In the "Choose Device" dialog that comes up to let you choose a physical device or emulator instance to run your app on, you can choose multiple items from the list:

[image: Screen Shot of Choose Device dialog, showing multiple selection from device list]

If you're not seeing this dialog, it's possible you clicked the "Use same device for future launches" button in the dialog. Go into the run configuration and reset the settings under "Target Device".

Comment: the choose dialog dont comes up if i have more than one pphysical device with usb cable connected! I want deploy on two physical devices parallel

Comment: I see this dialog. but only then, if i have only one device connected. this dialog dont come, if i have no device connected or more than one. 
In the Configuration i dont check the  "Use same device for future launches" button.

Comment: This feature seems to be broken in the latest version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your android devices have a different serial number.

Use 
      `adb devices`

to list serial number of connected devices.

Since they(IDEs) all use adb under the hood, I think the message "more than one device" is thrown from adb when it failed to uniquely identify devices.